# MVC can't find controller action when invoked with @Html.RenderAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call an action from a different controller in an MVC 5 page:

```
 Html.RenderAction("RenderHeader", "ParkDetailPage", new {...});
```

The error:

System.Web.HttpException
A public action method 'RenderHeader' was not found on controller 'xxx.Website.Controllers.ParkListerController'.

The RenderHeader method is defined as:

```
public ActionResult RenderHeader(int parkId, List<ParkDetailBlockBase> menuItems = null, List<string> highlights = null)
{ 
  //....
  return PartialView("Partials/_Header", viewModel);
}
```

What's the reason the controller name I use as the second argument is ignored?

Comment: It sounds like you have additional routing rules that override the default rule. Check or paste your routing here so we can help you not to override them

Comment: try using `[HttpGet]` attribute on the top of controller action.

Comment: Paste your routing rules also.

Comment: What happens when you access `/ParkDetailPage/RenderHeader` directly?

Comment: @Bellash: the list is rather long. What should I be on the lookout for? There is no overriding rule with the name 'ParkDetailPage' .

Comment: You render an action defined ParkDetailPageController but the error shows that you are led to ParkListerController; In My Opinion, the unique reason why you are led there is ROUTES being overridden